# How to perform lookup function of NaN rows in a column without overwrite the others value python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lookup

My goal is to lookup the information : "Team" from a Master dataset base on Year + Month + Name as a key ,
if there is NaN result , use only "Year" + "Name" as a second key to fill NaN rows .

## Goal :

```
# dataset with lookuped column "Team"
Name    Year    Month   KEY         KEY_ND     Team
0   Paul    2019    2   20192Paul   2019Paul    A
1   Paul    2019    1   20191Paul   2019Paul    A
2   Paul    2018    2   20182Paul   2018Paul    C
3   Paul    2018    1   20181Paul   2018Paul    B
4   Sue     2019    1    20191Sue   2019Sue     A
```

## Sample data and script i have tried so far

```
Master = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Paul","Paul","Paul","Sue"],
                   "Team": ["A","B","C", "A"],
                   "Year": ["2019","2018","2018","2019"],
                   "Month": [1,1,2,1]
                  })

xx = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Paul","Paul","Paul","Paul","Sue"],
                   "Year": ["2019","2019","2018","2018","2019"],
                   "Month": [2,1,2,1,1]
                  })


# Make First Key
Master_KEY = Master.assign(KEY = Master['Year'].astype(str) + 
Master['Month'].astype(str) + Master['Name'].astype(str))

# Make First Key
xx['KEY'] = xx['Year'] + xx['Month'].astype(str) + xx['Name']

# Make Second Key
Master_KEY = Master_KEY.assign(KEY_ND = Master['Year'].astype(str) + Master['Name'].astype(str))

# Make Second Key
xx['KEY_ND'] = xx['Year'] + xx['Name']

# First LOOKUP with first Key : Year + Month + Name 
xx = pd.merge(xx, Master_KEY[['KEY', 'Team']], on = 'KEY', how = 'left')

# MASK for NaN
x_mask = xx['Team'].isnull()

# Second LOOKUP with second Key : Year + Name 
xx.loc[x_mask, 'Team'] = pd.merge(xx,Master_KEY[['KEY_ND','Team']],
                 on = 'KEY_ND', how = 'left')
```

## Problem :

the last Second LOOKUP doesn't return the excepted result as
NaN value still exist.

```
xx
Name    Year    Month   KEY         KEY_ND  Team
0   Paul    2019    2   20192Paul   2019Paul    NaN
1   Paul    2019    1   20191Paul   2019Paul    A
2   Paul    2018    2   20182Paul   2018Paul    C
3   Paul    2018    1   20181Paul   2018Paul    B
4   Sue     2019    1   20191Sue    2019Sue     A
```

## This script is a problem :

```
# Second LOOKUP with second Key : Year + Name 
xx.loc[x_mask, 'Team'] = pd.merge(xx,Master_KEY[['KEY_ND','Team']],
                 on = 'KEY_ND', how = 'left')
```

*Apparently its a long and inefficient code , appreciate for any better recommendations is which clean & fast.

Comment: you can check  with x['team"].isna()  to find missing values  and replace it with something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with different `on` parameter and for second remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
Master1 = Master[['Name','Year', 'Team']].drop_duplicates(subset=['Name','Year'])
df1 = xx[['Name','Year']].merge(Master1, how='left')
df2 = xx.merge(Master, on=['Name','Year', 'Month'], how='left').fillna({'Team': df1['Team']})
print (df2)
   Name  Year  Month Team
0  Paul  2019      2    A
1  Paul  2019      1    A
2  Paul  2018      2    C
3  Paul  2018      1    B
4   Sue  2019      1    A
```

Your solution should be changed with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by keys columns with replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
Master = Master.assign(K1 =  Master['Year'].astype(str) + 
                             Master['Month'].astype(str) + 
                             Master['Name'].astype(str),
                       K2 =  Master['Year'].astype(str) + 
                             Master['Name'].astype(str))
xx = xx.assign(K1 =  xx['Year'].astype(str) + 
                     xx['Month'].astype(str) + 
                     xx['Name'].astype(str),
               K2 =  xx['Year'].astype(str) + 
                     xx['Name'].astype(str))

s1 = xx['K1'].map(Master.set_index('K1')['Team'])
s2 = xx['K2'].map(Master.drop_duplicates('K2').set_index('K2')['Team'])
xx['Team'] = s1.fillna(s2)
print (xx)
   Name  Year  Month         K1        K2 Team
0  Paul  2019      2  20192Paul  2019Paul    A
1  Paul  2019      1  20191Paul  2019Paul    A
2  Paul  2018      2  20182Paul  2018Paul    C
3  Paul  2018      1  20181Paul  2018Paul    B
4   Sue  2019      1   20191Sue   2019Sue    A
```

Answer (score 1):

slightly clean and readable solution is as below. Define a transform function which will add team column in each row based on your condition and apply that with the dataframe. It is readable and easily extensible for even more complex condition

```py
def transform(x):

    master_row = Master[(Master.Name==x.Name) & (Master.Year==x.Year)]
    if len(master_row)>1:
        temp_rows = master_row[master_row.Month == x.Month]
        master_row = temp_rows if len(temp_rows)>=0 else master_row

    x["Team"] = master_row.iloc[0].Team
    return x

xx.apply(transform, axis=1)
```